# Powershell system-object - select property with "filter"

Tags: powershell

Lets say I have an object named `something`:

```
Name                                           : name1
Group                                          : group1

Name                                           : name2
Group                                          : group2

Name                                           : name3
Group                                          : group1
```

I can access all names by:

```
$something | Select -ExpandProperty "Name";
```

it returns: `name1 name2 name3`

How would I select only the names from `group1`?
so it returns

`name1 name3`

Something like:

```
$something | Select -ExpandProperty "Name" -Where [Group -eq 'group1'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter:

```
$something |Where-Object Group -eq 'group1' |Select -ExpandProperty "Name"
```